# doctrine migrations 2 + zend framework 2 = is it possible?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I have used this guide http://www.jasongrimes.org/2012/01/using-doctrine-2-in-zend-framework-2/ and now I have a working Doctrine 2 + ZF2 software.

I use a versioning system and I want then use Doctrine MIGRATIONS tool to have a database migration system.

If I put on a shell `./doctrine-module orm:schema-tool:update` it works correctly, but if I use a migration tools for example `./doctrine-module migrations:status` the system give me an error:

> [Doctrine\DBAL\Migrations\MigrationException]
>     Migrations namespace must be configured in order to use Doctrine migrations.

Which configurations are needs? Does DoctrineOrmModule support Doctrine migration?

I have found this for zf1 http://moxune.com/blog/2011/10/configure-doctrine-migrations-2-zend_config/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you check [the current Travis CI CLI test](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineORMModule/blob/ee07234900d5cfa93598829fdb58373479480ed5/.travis/run-cli.sh#L15) for [DoctrineORMModule](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineORMModule) you will notice that there's a `--configuration` parameter pointing to an XML configuration, as described in [Doctrine Migrations documentation](https://github.com/doctrine/migrations-documentation). Setting that parameter and having DoctrineORMModule configured correctly should allow you to use the CLI.

Comment: ok... now 
`./doctrine-module migrations:diff --configuration="/.../config.xml"` works correctly, but the migration command ./doctrine-module migrations:migrate --configuration="/../config.xml" give me this error  `The helper "dialog" is not defined` here https://github.com/doctrine/migrations-documentation/blob/master/reference/en/introduction.txt there is the  solution but how can I add this helper? Can I use module.config.php instead of config.xml?

Comment: That is an issue I still have to fix :)