# Doctrine Migrations Namespace Error

Tags: php, doctrine, silex, doctrine-migrations

I am trying to setup doctrine migrations on top of silex framework. I installed it through composer.

```
"doctrine/dbal": "2.3.*",
"doctrine/migrations": "dev-master",
```

My console file:

```
...
$app['composer_loader']->add('Doctrine\DBAL\Migrations', __DIR__.'/../vendor/doctrine/migrations/lib/');

$helperSet = new \Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\HelperSet(array(
    "db" => new \Doctrine\DBAL\Tools\Console\Helper\ConnectionHelper($app['db']),
    "dialog" => new \Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\DialogHelper(),
));
$console->setHelperSet($helperSet);

$console->addCommands(array(
    // Migrations Commands
    new \Doctrine\DBAL\Migrations\Tools\Console\Command\DiffCommand(),
    new \Doctrine\DBAL\Migrations\Tools\Console\Command\ExecuteCommand(),
    new \Doctrine\DBAL\Migrations\Tools\Console\Command\GenerateCommand(),
    new \Doctrine\DBAL\Migrations\Tools\Console\Command\MigrateCommand(),
    new \Doctrine\DBAL\Migrations\Tools\Console\Command\StatusCommand(),
    new \Doctrine\DBAL\Migrations\Tools\Console\Command\VersionCommand()
));

$console->run();
```

However when I run migrations:status It outputs:

```
C:\htdocs\bitvenda\app>php console.php migrations:status

  [Doctrine\DBAL\Migrations\MigrationException]
  Migrations namespace must be configured in order to use Doctrine migrations
  .
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Dextervip, take a look on [this other issue][1], it might solver your issue. 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10620794/doctrine-migrations-2-zend-framework-2-is-it-possibile

Comment: @medina You are right, I missed it. Thank you. Do you know if is there any way to set default path to config file?

Comment: great! I've notice you figured it out yourself.. have fun! =)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As @medina commented. I missed the configuration file. I created the yml config file as below:

```
name: Doctrine Migrations
migrations_namespace: DoctrineMigrations
table_name: doctrine_migration_versions
migrations_directory: /data/DoctrineMigrations
```

And I passed the configuration file path as argument to get it working.

```
php console.php migrations:status --configuration=config/migrations.yml
```

To avoid passing it all the time, I changed working script dir to the same dir as the configuration file so that doctrine migrations loads it automatically

```
chdir(__DIR__.'/config');
```